# Is it normal a long idle time in Google Chrome console snapshot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, console

I have a javascript code that has a long "Idle" time in Google Chrome console snapshot, but i don't know if it is normal, below is a print.

[image]

Is this part of Javascript execution time?

Comment: What's wrong? I think idle time just means "Javascript isn't doing anything particular", which is not alarming. After working, it just sits there, waiting for something to happen on the page.

Comment: Yes it's look that scripting is the 30-40% of the page load time, so maybe you have to refactor javascripts code or find best solutions, I don't know If you can share some function or something for help to refactor.

Answer (score 2):

Idle time can't really be "too high"; if you record a longer snapshot with nothing else going on, with all else equal, idle time should be the only thing that increases.

Here's a trace from loading this very page, I left the recording running for 10 seconds:

[image]

You can see that the majority of that 10 seconds was spent doing nothing, because the page was loaded, ie the JavaScript engine was idle.